# Clojure aleph `http-server` does not respond body

Tags: linux, http, clojure

I started a clojure [aleph](https://aleph.io) http-server use the following codes:

```
(ns app.websvc
  (:require
   [aleph.http :as http]
   [compojure.core :as compojure :refer [GET POST]]
   [ring.middleware.params :as params]))

(defn root-handler
  [req]
  {:status 200
   :headers {"content-type" "text/plain"}
   :body "wallet backend"})

(def http-handler
  (params/wrap-params
   (compojure/routes
    (GET "/" [] root-handler))))

(http/start-server http-handler {:port 8080})
```

I tested it using this:

```
$ curl -v "http://localhost:8080/"
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
```

It seems connected but not respond any thing. What could the problem be?

**I run the same code on my local machine, the `curl` command respond correctly, but not work (the problem described above) on my new bought remote cloud host.**

### updated

I did this:

```
$ telnet localhost 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.0
```

also hangs.

Comment: Is `:status 20` a typo?

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo.

Comment: It seems not related to firewall. I did this: `sudo ufw disable` but still has the same problem.

Comment: I've solved this. I scp my source files and run `lein run` again, and the http-server no longer hangs.

Comment: @cmal don't forget you can write an answer your own question.